# Minimal Lync 2013 Setup

Tags: windows-server-2012, lync-2013

I would like to install a Lync 2013 server at home. What would be the minimum requirements for it? I've seen the requirements and they seem pretty hefty, just want to know what I need for a basic set up. This will be for up to 5 users. I would like users to be able to connect from outside the network as well.

From what I've been able to find, it looks like I'll need 3 servers. A domain controller, a lync front end server, and an edge server (for external connectivity, and it will need 2 network cards). Is that really all necessary? And how would they need to be connected (I've never connected a machine with multiple network cards)? Do they all have to be separate machines, or can I use VMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements you have seen are right :

1. Lync needs Active Directory : so you need to setup a domain
   controler with DNS Role.
2. You need a Lync Standard Edition Front-End Server (for Mediation
   role with SQL Server Express for backend database included).
3. You need a separate Edge Server (in a DMZ) for external user access (Edge role
   cannot be installed on Front-End server).
   The Edge server needs 2 network cards : one on DMZ side, the other one on Lan side (how             to setup this is a full other question).
4. [A firewall](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425891.aspx)
5. For best practices : a Reverse Proxy

Of course, assuming you don't want archiving, monitoring, Persistent Chat, WAC, Enterprise voice nor Exchange UM role.

For Lync servers, install 64 bits OS.

[You need an internal Certification Authority Server and external certificates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398094.aspx) (or you could provide your internal certificates to your external users).

You also need a [domain name and public DNS records](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398758.aspx).

Every servers can be Virtual Machines.

IMHO :
Lync is not really designed to be installed on-premise "at home". It is not a home toy but an enterprise tool. Except if you want to play and learn i would suggest Lync Online.

As a note : [this site is dedicated to professional system and network administrators, not for home or development environment.](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)